# multi-node registration failures on mesos

Tags: apache, mesos, marathon, mesosphere

I have a simple mesos cluster 1 master and 2 agents. All are VPS and connected over virtual lan. When I start the master and agent services, I see that I was able to see both the agents activated on the master via mesos UI. When I deploy a simple application (cmd: "echo hello; sleep 5") via marathon UI, the mesos UI shows that the program executed and completed on agent 1, however, on agent 2 the application status is ALWAYS staged.

In the log, for agent 2, I see that agent 2 never registers, while agent 1 does. Below is agent 2 log.

```
I1114 07:54:05.399139  8985 slave.cpp:251] Flags at startup: --appc_simple_discovery_uri_prefix="http://" --appc_store_dir="/tmp/mesos/store/appc" --authenticate_http_executors="false" --authenticate_http_readonly="false" --authenticate_http_readwrite="false" --authenticatee="crammd5" --authentication_backoff_factor="1secs" --authorizer="local" --cgroups_cpu_enable_pids_and_tids_count="false" --cgroups_enable_cfs="false" --cgroups_hierarchy="/sys/fs/cgroup" --cgroups_limit_swap="false" --cgroups_root="mesos" --container_disk_watch_interval="15secs" --containerizers="mesos" --default_role="*" --disallow_sharing_agent_pid_namespace="false" --disk_watch_interval="1mins" --docker="docker" --docker_kill_orphans="true" --docker_registry="https://registry-1.docker.io" --docker_remove_delay="6hrs" --docker_socket="/var/run/docker.sock" --docker_stop_timeout="0ns" --docker_store_dir="/tmp/mesos/store/docker" --docker_volume_checkpoint_dir="/var/run/mesos/isolators/docker/volume" --enforce_container_disk_quota="false" --executor_registration_timeout="1mins" --executor_reregistration_timeout="2secs" --executor_shutdown_grace_period="5secs" --fetcher_cache_dir="/tmp/mesos/fetch" --fetcher_cache_size="2GB" --frameworks_home="" --gc_delay="1weeks" --gc_disk_headroom="0.1" --hadoop_home="" --help="false" --hostname_lookup="true" --http_command_executor="false" --http_heartbeat_interval="30secs" --initialize_driver_logging="true" --ip="10.0.0.5" --isolation="posix/cpu,posix/mem" --launcher="linux" --launcher_dir="/usr/libexec/mesos" --logbufsecs="0" --logging_level="INFO" --master="10.0.0.6:5050" --max_completed_executors_per_framework="150" --oversubscribed_resources_interval="15secs" --perf_duration="10secs" --perf_interval="1mins" --port="5051" --qos_correction_interval_min="0ns" --quiet="false" --recover="reconnect" --recovery_timeout="15mins" --registration_backoff_factor="1secs" --revocable_cpu_low_priority="true" --runtime_dir="/var/run/mesos" --sandbox_directory="/mnt/mesos/sandbox" --strict="true" --switch_user="true" --systemd_enable_support="true" --systemd_runtime_directory="/run/systemd/system" --version="false" --work_dir="/var/lib/mesos/agent"
I1114 07:54:05.401047  8985 slave.cpp:565] Agent resources: [{"name":"cpus","scalar":{"value":4.0},"type":"SCALAR"},{"name":"mem","scalar":{"value":6959.0},"type":"SCALAR"},{"name":"disk","scalar":{"value":43131.0},"type":"SCALAR"},{"name":"ports","ranges":{"range":[{"begin":31000,"end":32000}]},"type":"RANGES"}]
I1114 07:54:05.404896  8985 slave.cpp:573] Agent attributes: [  ]
I1114 07:54:05.404913  8985 slave.cpp:582] Agent hostname: 10.0.0.5
I1114 07:54:05.405012  8982 status_update_manager.cpp:177] Pausing sending status updates
I1114 07:54:05.405889  8983 state.cpp:64] Recovering state from '/var/lib/mesos/agent/meta'
I1114 07:54:05.405936  8983 state.cpp:722] No committed checkpointed resources found at '/var/lib/mesos/agent/meta/resources/resources.info'
I1114 07:54:05.406015  8983 state.cpp:108] Failed to find the latest agent from '/var/lib/mesos/agent/meta'
I1114 07:54:05.411798  8987 status_update_manager.cpp:203] Recovering status update manager
I1114 07:54:05.411916  8988 containerizer.cpp:609] Recovering containerizer
I1114 07:54:05.413099  8985 provisioner.cpp:416] Provisioner recovery complete
I1114 07:54:05.413230  8984 slave.cpp:6295] Finished recovery
I1114 07:54:05.413630  8984 status_update_manager.cpp:177] Pausing sending status updates
I1114 07:54:05.413666  8981 slave.cpp:971] New master detected at master@10.0.0.6:5050
I1114 07:54:05.413694  8981 slave.cpp:995] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
I1114 07:54:05.413712  8981 slave.cpp:1006] Detecting new master
```

agent #1 log is the same as above, but in the end it has these extra lines

```
I1114 07:57:17.609352  1645 slave.cpp:1006] Detecting new master
I1114 07:57:18.426383  1642 slave.cpp:1286] Re-registered with master master@10.0.0.6:5050
I1114 07:57:18.426463  1645 status_update_manager.cpp:184] Resuming sending status updates
I1114 07:57:18.426465  1642 slave.cpp:1323] Forwarding total oversubscribed resources {}
```

am I configuring something wrong? or is this some bug in mesos? (unlikely I guess).

Answer (score 0):

Firewall was enabled
Had to open up port 5050 and 5051 on agent 2. Now it works fine
Ufw allow 5050
Ufw allow 5051